# How to get the values of all managed properties in SharePoint search Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, managed-property, sharepoint-search

I am currently using the SharePoint search rest api to get the search result. Below is the code I am using

```
var url="http://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/_api/search/query?querytext='SearchTerm+AND+ListId:718158df-a888-434d-86f7-207aeb361989+AND+IsDocument=True'&selectproperties='Path,Author,Title,PartyInfo'";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var totalLen = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.RowCount;
        console.log("Total Data: "+ totalLen);
        for(var i=0;i<totalLen;i++)
        {
            var docTitle = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i].Cells.results[4].Value;
            var author = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i].Cells.results[3].Value;
            var path = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i].Cells.results[2].Value;
            var partyInfo = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i].Cells.results[7].Value;
            console.log("Title: "+ docTitle);
            console.log("Author: "+ author);
            console.log("Path: "+ path);
            console.log("Party Info: "+ partyInfo);

        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

where **PartyInfo** is the name of the custom column in a document library whose ID I have passed in the URL (to limit the result for testing purpose only) and also the name of the managed property. The above code is working fine and I am able to get the value of my custom column through managed property name by defining it in `selectproperties` tag in the URL.

My question is how can I get the value of all the managed properties associated with the current item without passing their name in `selectproperties` tag. My requirement is to make a global search page across a site collection where there will be many subsites and lists. So it will not be possible to know the name of the custom column everytime.

So something like `selectproperties='*'` will do the trick for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, only standard managed properties are included by default:
http://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:ABC'

so we add the selectproperties parameter explicity to the query.
Also, selectproperties also should be configured as managed properties with option Selectable.

So i don't think what you are trying to achieve is feasible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the content type is also a good approach to achieve the task

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can, as described in [How to find all managed properties of a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/searchguys/how-to-find-all-managed-properties-of-a-document).

Basically, if you set your `refiner` option to `managedproperties(filter=600/0/*)` you will get all properties in the `RefinementResults` in the response